# Cannot echo bash variable from single line command

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, filenames, cut

I have the following file names where I am trying to relabel `v5.4b` to `v5.7`:

```
v5.4b_lvl-1.e8974326
v5.4b_lvl-1.o8974326
v5.4b_lvl-1.pe8974326
v5.4b_lvl-1.po8974326
v5.4b_lvl-2.1.e8974303
v5.4b_lvl-2.1.o8974303
v5.4b_lvl-2.1.pe8974303
v5.4b_lvl-2.1.po8974303
v5.4b_lvl-2.2.e8974304
v5.4b_lvl-2.2.o8974304
v5.4b_lvl-2.2.pe8974304
v5.4b_lvl-2.2.po8974304
v5.4b_lvl-3.1.e8974305
v5.4b_lvl-3.1.o8974305
v5.4b_lvl-3.1.pe8974305
v5.4b_lvl-3.1.po8974305
v5.4b_lvl-4.1.e8974327
v5.4b_lvl-4.1.o8974327
v5.4b_lvl-4.1.pe8974327
v5.4b_lvl-4.1.po8974327
```

I can't do `mv v5.4b_* v5.7_*` because it thinks `v5.7_*` is a directory so I am trying a `for-loop` but I can't get it to work

I am trying the recommended answer from this SO post [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) but getting a bunch of empty lines.

**What am I doing incorrectly? How can I save the output of `cut` to `SUFFIX` so I can `mv $i v5.7_$SUFFIX`?**

```
-bash-4.1$ for i in v5.4b*; do echo $i | SUFFIX=`cut -f2 -d'_'`; echo ${SUFFIX}; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `echo $i` in the wrong place.  The output of that command needs to be piped to `cut` for it to read anything, then the result is assigned to `SUFFIX`:

```
for i in v5.4b*
do 
    SUFFIX=`echo $i | cut -f2 -d'_'`
    echo ${SUFFIX}
done
```

Comment: `for i in v5.4b*; do SUFFIX=`echo $i | cut -f2 -d'_'`; mv $i v5.7_${SUFFIX}; done` NICE thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you rename utility then just do:

```
rename -n 's/v5\4.b/v5.7/' v5.4b*
```

PS: `-n` is for dry-run. You may remove it later for real renaming.

If `rename` is not available then use:

```
for i in v5.4b*; do
   echo mv "$i" "${i/v5.4b/v5.7}"
done
```

Remove 'echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: I'm definitely going to use this in the future.  I had to mark the other one as correct since that was specific to the questino but thanks a lot for sharing this.  I upvoted.